# Can I create a common ground between a rectifier and USB powered microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, grounding, rectifier

I am working on firmware to decode the Marklin (MM/MFX) track protocols using a PSOC 5LP micro controller.

Is it possible to create a common ground between the track ground, micro controller ground, and rectifier -ve output?

**Background:**

During design, the micro controller is powered over USB from a windows pc, and actively uses a UART for informational purposes. Ultimately, the micro controller will be track powered.

The Marklin train controller (Mobile Station 2) is powered from a 36VA switched mode power supply and interfaces with a track controller box. The track controller box puts out a square wave "digital signal" that both powers and provides encoded messages to the trains/switches.

The signal below is an example (clipped by the Saleae Logic Pro 16):

[image]

This Track Signal is fed into the GPIO input p5_5 on the schematic and a current limiting resistor (R1) is used keep the current within over-voltage tolerances.

The circuit below creates a common ground point between the track ground and micro controller. The MB6S bridge rectifier produces ~17VDC.

As I would like to send some signals back from the micro controller to logic powered by the rectified voltage, I would like to create a common ground point.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjHBOu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Currently I measure a potential difference of 12.98V between the two ground points I have created (point A and B on the schematic), so have not connected them together.

Comment: Do you need the full bridge rectifier, and could you get away with a half bridge?

Comment: I picked a full bridge rectifier that matched the component on the commercial decoder. If I can still achieve at least 6V from the depicted signal, to feed into a 3.3V LDO, that would be fine.

Comment: you probably need some sort of isolation, eg: optocoupler  to bridge the tow domains tjhen you ca produce a signal referenced to the most negative of the two AC lines (using diodes to pick which) that signal will the be usable by yher rectifier powered device.

Comment: Is the track 'ground' actually grounded, or it is floating with respect to mains ground?

Comment: The track ground is supplied from a connector box that is connected to a train controller. The train controller is powered by a 36VA switching power supply. There is no ground pin on the power supply. The potential between the track ground and microcontroller GND is very near 0V. Hope that answers the question given the context.